How can i show all attributes label on the product list page for every product that has the attribute property set to "Used in Product Listing"?
I am searching for a while now how i can display all attributes labels for every product on the catagory product list page that has the option "Used in Product Listing" set to yes of the attribute. For example:
I have products with attributeset calls lan cables, now i want to show the attribute label length, color, cable catagory, etc. on the product list page when these attributes are set to Used in Product Listing. Can someone help me with this?
